# Splitting an excel file into dataframes and then creating two new files from them in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry about the poorly worded title.  On this project I am bringing in multiple excel files that need to be manipulated and then sent back out as multiple csv files(eventually heading into BigQuery).  Several things I am trying to do is eliminate the final 6 rows (this is a watermark that is not needed), and then create two separate csv files.  The excel files come in looking something like this:

[image]

I am removing the final 6 rows with a skipfooter and then am creating the first dataframe with columns 1-181 and the second data frame with columns 182-225.  I can split them out but have had issues using an append or merge (probably doing it incorrectly).  What I want to do is in the second csv to have the PID inserted and filled in in a new first column, something like this:

[image]

My big questions are how do I correctly combine(append) that PID on all rows needed and how do I loop through hundreds of excel files that I am bringing in so that I am making sure the correct PID is going to the correct Record# tests?  At this time I am just working with one file so I can see if it works correctly.  In the code below my append will append index_df to second_df but I am unsure how to fill rest of the rows with that same PID.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv
raw_data_frame = pd.read_excel('\\\\file01\\incoming\\mat\ID5.xlsx', skipfooter=6)
first_df = raw_data_frame.iloc[:, 1:182]
second_df = raw_data_frame.iloc[:, 182:225]
index_df = raw_data_fram.iloc[0:1, 4:5]
df_combine = df_id.append(second_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The split part of the problem was you said was already working well, and you can use append and merge to accomplish this, but I think [`df.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) (`df.insert(0, column="PID", value=df["PID"])`) follow by a `ffill` works better in this case. For the iteration over the `xls` files you can use a for loop with [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to find all the documents in a pre-defined folder. The way  the output files are generated will have to be adapted to your problem, here I opted to place each `csv` file pair inside a new folder with the respective `PID` number.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

INPUT_FOLDER = "input_xls"
OUTPUT_FOLDER = "output_xls"

for excel_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(INPUT_FOLDER, '*.xls')):

    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, skipfooter=6, dtype=str)
    print(df)

    # change to 182 here
    COL_SPLIT = 5

    first_df = df.iloc[:,:COL_SPLIT]
    first_df = first_df.dropna(how="all")

    second_df = df.iloc[:, COL_SPLIT:]
    second_df = second_df.dropna(how="all")
    second_df.insert(0, column="PID", value=df["PID"])
    second_df["PID"].ffill(inplace=True)

    print(first_df)
    print(second_df)

    pid = first_df.loc[0, "PID"]

    out_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, f'PID-{pid}')
    os.makedirs(out_path, exist_ok=True)
    first_df.to_csv(os.path.join(out_path,"first.csv"), index=False)
    second_df.to_csv(os.path.join(out_path,"second.csv"), index=False)
```

```
.
├── input_xls
│   ├── excel_with_PID111.xls
│   ├── excel_with_PID1765.xls
│   ├── excel_with_PID232.xls
│   └── excel_with_PID67867.xls
├── output_xls
│   ├── PID-111
│   │   ├── first.csv
│   │   └── second.csv
│   ├── PID-1755
│   │   ├── first.csv
│   │   └── second.csv
│   ├── PID-232
│   │   ├── first.csv
│   │   └── second.csv
│   └── PID-67867
│       ├── first.csv
│       └── second.csv
```

Dataframe **first_df**

```
   PID Last First Gender Age
0  111  Guy  Some      M  35
```

Dataframe **second_df**

```
   PID Record# testl test2 test3
0  111     222   378    24   371
1  111     223   319    28   311
2  111     224   207    20   210
3  111     225   100    30   200
```